# What are the parity bits in a (7,3)-linear code

Tags: hamming, code-based-cryptography

If I have a linear (7,4)-Hamming Code I know that the last 3 bits are the parity bits but I just have seen that there are multiple linear codes like (7,3) for example the code with basis:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

(!Notice that it's not important if this is correct or not)

Are the first 3 bits the parity bits? Or how can I understand this matrix?

Thank You very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, let $G$ be a basis matrix for a linear code with the basis codewords as the rows of the matrix. The matrix $G$ can be transformed using column swaps and row additions into systematic form
$$\begin{bmatrix} I|A\end{bmatrix}$$
the bit positions corresponding to the columns incident with $A$ are then called parity check bits. There is also the parity check matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} -A^T|I\end{bmatrix}$$
whose rows are orthogonal to all of the codewords.

In your example, the code is not in systematic form, but we can put it in systematic form by (for example) adding the first row to the second and third and swapping the 2nd and 7th columns to obtain the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&1&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
For this choice of systemisation the last 4 bit positions (which correspond to bit positions 4,5,6 and 2 of the original code) would be considered the parity-check bits.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Now it's clear to me how to solve things like that!